# Closure-Mistake index of array in self-implemented useState-Function (for learning purposes)

Tags: reactjs, closures, use-state

I´m wrapping my head around the useState-Function of react and trying to implement sort of a simple copy-version for my own (just for learning purposes basically). I encounter a really silly problem I'm just stuck with. It´s probably so simple that I´m angry wih myself afterwards... :)

```
let state = []

const myState = (init) => {
    state[0] = init
    const setState = newState => state[0] = newState
    return [state, setState] // return [state[0], setState] does not work
}

const [count, setCount] = myState(0)

console.log(count)
setCount(1)
console.log(count)
```

This version above does work, in fact I get logged out the state-array correctly: [0],[1]

But when I return [state[0], setState] in my myState-Function, I get: 0, 0

What is going wrong here? (I´m doing it with just node.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short words, the result you are getting is expected. It happens in this way, because `state[0]` is a primitive value and when you return `[state[0], setState]` from your `myState` hook you just return the primitive value, which  not updated anymore after this call `myState(0)`.

When you return the whole state (`return [state, setState]`) you return a link to this array, so that's why you are able to see updated values.

To dive deeper I'd recommend to learn how React renders components and updates the state. Without it, learning just how `useState` works is not enough to get the whole picture.

`React` works in a bit complex way, so after changing the state in the hooks, it internally triggers re-rendering and as a result you are getting the updated state in your components

Comment: Thanks. I know that there is more to react in terms of rerendering and so on. I was stuck because of that linking to array vs. primitive value . On what topic could I inform myself more about that?

Comment: just googling something like "primitive values vs objects js" https://medium.com/@junshengpierre/javascript-primitive-values-object-references-361cfc1cbfb0